# Latch for different task types

Tags: java, concurrency

I am looking for a java concurrency solution to the following problem.

There are some tasks being run, and a section of code C.

- C must wait for all tasks to complete. (With a timeout)
- No tasks may commence until C has finished.

I have looked through the java.concurrency package and I found a few things of interest, but nothing seems to work quite right:

- Phasers would allow one way blocking, but not two way.
- Semaphores, ForkJoinTasks and others have counter-type features but none seem to do what I want.

I believe I could construct something using a phaser and a lock like so:

```
void C() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        phaser.awaitAdvanceInterruptibly(phase, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Start work anyway if a task is taking too long.
        doWork();
    }
}

void someTask() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        phaser.register();
    }
    doTask().thenRun(
        () -> phaser.arriveAndDeregister()
    );
}
```

Now while I'm fairly sure this would work, I'm also aware its a bad idea to try to build your own concurrency solution. Is there a better way of doing this?

If there isn't, what would I use for the `phase` argument?

**Edit**: This problem is within a project involving a web client connection, and therefore the tasks arrive unpredictably. However, it is possible that this situation could be avoided by more careful design.

Comment: You could use two `CountDownLatch`s. One created with 1 to start tasks when section C is completed and another created with N to start section C only when N tasks have finished

Comment: @Ivan that would work, except that I do not know how many tasks will be run, or when. I have added relevant context to the question.

Comment: C must wait for all tasks to complete, but at the same time that tasks cannot commence until C has finished. Am I the only one who see contradiction here?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov C does not depend on any task completing, but it must wait for any in-progress tasks. Therefore, a task that arrives after C must wait for C to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem in java.util.concurrent.locks, which is perfect for my use case.

```
StampedLock lock;

void C() {
    long stamp = lock.tryWriteLock(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    doWork();
    lock.unlockWrite(stamp);
}

void someTask() {
    long stamp = lock.readLock();
    doTask().thenRun(() -> lock.unlockRead(stamp));
}
```

The key with the [StampedLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html) class is that the readLock() is not exclusive, whereas the writeLock() is exclusive. It also supports timeouts, similar to the regular Lock.

Answer (score 0):

This being a specialized use case, I think we'll need to use multiple concurrency utilities for co-ordination. The below program should do it. Please feel free to post questions of any parts aren't clear -

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TestClass {

    private volatile int numOfActiveTasks = 0;
    private Semaphore cSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    private Semaphore taskSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    private Object tasksLock = new Object();

    //Test method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

        //Launch some task threads
        ExecutorService taskES = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        IntStream.range(1, 11).forEach((i) -> taskES.submit(() -> {
            try {
                testClass.executeTask();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }));

        //Launch some C threads
        ExecutorService cES = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        IntStream.range(1, 5).forEach((i) -> cES.submit(() -> {
            try {
                testClass.C();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }));

        taskES.shutdown();
        cES.shutdown();
    }


    void C() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            cSemaphore.acquire();

            //If tasks are running, wait at-least n seconds
            this.taskSemaphore.tryAcquire(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            print("C started running");
            doCsWork();

        } finally {
            cSemaphore.release();
            print("C stopped running");
        }
    }

    void executeTask() throws InterruptedException {

        //Do not start while C is running
        cSemaphore.acquire();
        cSemaphore.release();

        synchronized (tasksLock) {
            ++numOfActiveTasks;
            taskSemaphore.tryAcquire();
            print("A task started running. Total " + numOfActiveTasks + " tasks running");
        }

        doTasksWork();

        synchronized (tasksLock) {
            --numOfActiveTasks;
            if (numOfActiveTasks == 0) {
                taskSemaphore.release();
            }
            print("A task stopped running. Total " + numOfActiveTasks + " tasks remaining");
        }
    }

    void doCsWork() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    void doTasksWork() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    void print(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```